# Average multiple rows across long dataset removing any NAs

Tags: r

I have the following data (with 1000's of rows):

| ID | score | test |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 45 | 1 |
| 1 | 55 | 2 |
| 1 | 23 | 3 |
| 1 | 56 | 4 |
| 2 | 82 | 1 |
| 2 | 52 | 2 |
| 2 | NA | 3 |
| 2 | 21 | 4 |

etc. to 500 IDs

I seeking to remove the NAs and calculate the mean of each students score before moving ahead. So it would look like this

| ID | Score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 44.75 |
| 2 | 51.7 |
| 3 | 56.4 |

etc. to 500

I really can't work out the appropriate R code to use to do this. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can group by 'ID' and `summarise` the 'Score' by applying the `mean` with `na.rm = TRUE`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   summarise(Score = mean(Score, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or with `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(Score ~ ID, df1, mean, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = NULL)
```